# What's wrong with this sidebar?

Tags: html, css

So, I have this sidebar but it won't work (if you wanna see what i mean, go to https://ykmmorgan.github.io/ZinexiumRBLX) and you'll see. It's supposed to look like https://www.cssscript.com/demo/responsive-fixed-sidebar/#. If you wanna see the code, it's here: https://github.com/YkmMorgan/ZinexiumRBLX/blob/main/styles.css,
https://github.com/YkmMorgan/ZinexiumRBLX/blob/main/sidebar.css
https://github.com/YkmMorgan/ZinexiumRBLX/blob/main/index.html. Thank you.

Comment: remove  `width: 150px` from `ul`

Comment: i cant find width: 150px in ul.. wdym?
(sorry i havent slept)

Comment: `.sidebar__nav` selector. To **stylesheet.css** - https://ibb.co/3vGbpt1

Comment: thats not in the actual code tho..i dont know how to remove that, cause its not in the actual code. this is the actual code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/YkmMorgan/ZinexiumRBLX/main/styles.css

Comment: wait im so sorry i read stylesheet.css as styles.css, sorry for wasting your time!!

Comment: @s.kuznetsov do you know how to fix the animation on the sidebar?? cause when i hover my cursor over it, it just opens in half a second but its supposed to open a little slower/drag open or whatever

Comment: Yes, I know how to make animation. Use `transition` or `@keyframes`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227444/discussion-between-morganinnit-and-s-kuznetsov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not good for you...

> ul {
> width: 150px;
> }
> Clear this at first.

Thanks
Cs

Comment: thats not in the code, thats in devtools but not in the code

Comment: Wow very interesting.  I try to use a  reset.css file 
[link] https://github.com/murtaugh/HTML5-Reset

Comment: i had to do what u said, i just didnt see it at first sorry